# win 10 - resize adjacent window?

Tags: windows-10, resizing

When I drag a window to the side of a screen, to say, use half the screen, and then drag another window to the other side ot use the other half of the screen, is there anything I can do to resize both at the same time?

Because trying to resize the one means I'll have to manually adjust the other because they'll quite simply overlap. This is very inconvenient and frankly, it should've been a no-brainer to make the windows resize together automatically.

**EDIT**

Edition: Windows 10 Pro

Version: 1703

Build: 15063.608

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you using? Because when I resize one window the other one automatically adjusts with it. I'm using Creators update (1703)

Comment: @Bungicasse dxdiag reports "Windows 10 Pro 64-Bit -Version (10.0, Build 15063)"

Comment: @Bungicasse ah, and I see that's the BUILD version. The settings also report 1703 as a version. Updated my post to include the correct version information.